# Estimating table size using mysql

Tags: android, mysql, sqlite

Scenario: 
Android application having database with more than ten table.
Have to fetch and store data from server to sq-lite(mobile) database.
In order to perform this operation efficiently I planned to calculate the each table's row size.
with the length allocated for attributes.

```
 ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|  table_name             |  Size of single row with defined attributes length     |
|----------------------------------------------------------------------------------|
|  table_1                |                   size                                 |
|----------------------------------------------------------------------------------|
|  table_2                |                   size                                 |
|----------------------------------------------------------------------------------|
|  table_3                |                   size                                 |
 ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Is any mysql query to calculate the table's single row length regarding length allocated to attributes while creation?

like I found the query which shows the size of a table:

```
SELECT table_name AS "Table", 
round(((data_length + index_length) / 1024 / 1024), 2) "Size in MB" 
FROM information_schema.TABLES 
WHERE table_schema = "$DB_NAME"
 AND table_name = "$TABLE_NAME";
```

or this query to list the size of every table in the database, largest first:

```
SELECT table_name AS "Tables", 
round(((data_length + index_length) / 1024 / 1024), 2) "Size in MB" 
FROM information_schema.TABLES 
WHERE table_schema = "$DB_NAME"

ORDER BY (data_length + index_length) DESC;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not believe you really need to know the size of each row. You could calculate their average, by dividing the size of the table with the total number of records.

```
select count(*) into @tableRecordCount from table_name;

select table_name as "Tables".
round(((data_length + index_length) / (1024 * 1024 * @tableRecordCount), 2) "Size in MB per record"
from information_schema.TABLES
where table_schame = "$DB_NAME"
order by (data_length + index_length) desc;
```